# JQuery functions

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a function to load content into a page. If I use it this way works fine

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#nav li a').click(function(){                      
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
        $('#load').remove();
        $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
        $('#load').fadeIn('normal',loadContent);
        function loadContent() {
            $('#content').append($('<div>').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent()))
        }
        function showNewContent() {
            $('#content').fadeIn('normal',hideLoader());
        }
        function hideLoader() {
            $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
        }
        return false;   
    });
});
```

but when I want to make it function

```
jQuery.addc = function(){

        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
        $('#load').remove();
        $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
        $('#load').fadeIn('normal',loadContent);
        function loadContent() {
            $('#content').append($('<div>').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent()))
        }
        function showNewContent() {
            $('#content').fadeIn('normal',hideLoader());
        }
        function hideLoader() {
            $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
        }
        return false;   
};
```

stop working, when I call the function with onclick

```
<ul id="nav">

        <li a href="index.html" onclick="$.addc();"> Index </a> </li>
</ul>
```

I don't know whats happening because first code works fine, but second don't, If anyone can help me please
I also try `$.fn.addc = function ()` but don't work

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I've modified the script, now works better, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Extract only the innards into a function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav li a').click($.addc);
}); 

$.addc = function() {                    
    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href') + ' #content';

    $('#load').remove();
    $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal',loadContent);

    function loadContent() {
        $('#content').append($('<div>').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent()))
    }

    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').fadeIn('normal',hideLoader());
    }

    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }

    return false;   
};
```

Answer (score 0):

the **whole idea** (or at least a main one) is to remove inline js.

stick to your first solution,

or what you can do is:

```
var clicked = function(){
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
        $('#load').remove();
        $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
        $('#load').fadeIn('normal',loadContent);
        function loadContent() {
            $('#content').append($('<div>').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent()))
        }
        function showNewContent() {
            $('#content').fadeIn('normal',hideLoader());
        }
        function hideLoader() {
            $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
        }
        return false; 
    }

$('#nav li a').live('click', clicked);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the context of `this` is changing. `this` in your first code snipped corresponds to the element of your selector; one of the elements in `#nav li a`. In your second snippet, `this` does not reference to same thing, so it doesnt work.

In addition, it's bad form to attach a "static" function to the jQuery object when it is specific to an implementation of yours. You should extract that logic into a method, and then call that like so:

```
onclick="myMethod();"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your context is all wrong.  In the original, you have:

`$(document)`, so `this` will be the document (or maybe the jQuery wrapper for the document).  You will need to set the context.

For example, create a new function:

```
function aoeu () {
    $.fn.addc.call(document);
}
```

I would change the `$(this)` to `$(document)` instead.  This will make your life a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `this`, which in the first case was passed in by jQuery, but in the second case it is up to you to pass it in.

e.g. `onclick="addc(this);"` and give your function a signature of `function addc(this) {...}`

(there is not need to overload the jQuery namespace for a custom and very specific function)